# find the next and previous row of an activerecord obj

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, i have the following function in one of my controller page.

```
def tree
@jstree = Sub.find_by_sql("Select sequence, depth, node, imageid, range from.....several joins")
end
```

I now want to loop through the resultset and perform some actions depending on the value of the prev and next row.

```
<% @jstree.each do |tree| %>
<%= tree.sequence %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to know how to get the next and previous row value within the above loop

Many many thanks for all suggestions provided :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you actually need to use it (and obviously the first and last records won't have previous/next elements).

If you do an `each_with_index` you have the index and can use normal array access:

```
@jstree.each_with_index do |elem, n|
    prev_elem = @jstree[n-1] unless n == 0
    next_elem = @jstree[n+1] unless n == @jstree.size-1
    # Etc.
    do_stuff_with_next if next_elem # Or
    if next_elem
        do_stuff
        do_other_different_stuff
    end
end
```

Comment: nextElem.depth is giving me an error msg. undefined method `depth' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @tanya You need to see if it exists before you can actually use it. Plus there was a minor bug.

Comment: @Dave: the camel-cased variables hurt my eyes :) @tanya: when you are on the last element, `nextElem` will be `nil`, obviously.

Comment: @Dave: Thank you so much. It's working great now. The 'if next_elem' condition was missing, that's the reason i was getting the aforementioned error. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this suits your needs: `@jstree.each_with_index do |tree, index|` and then you can find previous and next by `@jstree[index-1]` and `@jstree[index+1]` (don't forget to check if you are on the first or last item).

Comment: If you are on the last element inside `@jstree`, or always?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use each_with_index instead:

```
@jstree.each_with_index do |item, index|
...
```

Or if you need something more complex here's a plugin that looks taylored for this: [acts_as_ordered](http://svn.viney.net.nz/things/rails/plugins/acts_as_ordered/README).